# Get module contents

Tags: haskell

The `:browse`, `:info` and `:type` GHCi commands are very convenient.

Is it possible to get the same information programmaticaly in a Haskell program? That is, to get the exported functions from a module, the types of stuff, etc.

Comment: Eh, sorry? What? I have been looking around with Hoogle and Google and not found anything.

Comment: You can use the GHC API. I'm not aware of a simpler way.

Comment: I can imagine there _might_ be a TH-based solution..?

Comment: Thanks for you answers. Ill go a head and post another question, for the solution of the original problem: Is there are generated sources for Emacs auto completion for Haskell?

Comment: Ah, the GHC API of course. Fiddly, but seems possible. Thanks! This would be marked as the solutions was it not a comment.

Comment: This might be a good lead: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12075530/how-can-haskell-quasiquotation-be-used-for-replacing-tokens-on-the-haskell-level

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Daniel Fischer commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9343032/get-module-contents#comment11793168_9343032):

> You can use the GHC API. I'm not aware of a simpler way.

Seems to be fiddly but to work fine. And I guess this is how `:info` works in GHCi. Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 5):

`:browse` - when a Haskell program is compiled, no (useful) information is kept about which module something came from, so your program wouldn't be able to access that information.

`:type` - Unless you're using [Data.Typeable](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/base/Data-Typeable.html), types aren't visible at all at runtime. Types in Haskell are mostly for the compiler to check to correctness/safety of code.

`:info` - See above.

Comment: It should be possible to read that static info from the .hi interface files.

Comment: Hm, maybe only :browse would make sense to do on static info in a .hi file.

Comment: The reason that this answer is not relevant is that I am not interested in a program that manipulates its own meta info, but a program that reads the info of a module that is stored on disk. This information is stored in the `.hi` files, and can be read.

Answer (score 3):

for getting functions of a module at compile time - the `language-haskell-extract` package could be interesting to you. It helps you extracting functions according to a regular expression.

http://hackage.haskell.org/package/language-haskell-extract-0.2.1

Comment: The functions in that package extracts the names of the functions of the calling module. That might be useful sometimes, but it does not solve my problem.